# Remote host terminated the handshake In JMeter

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner, handshake, sslexception

I got three kind of errors while using load run via JMeter. Probably this can be happen due to SSL issue but can't identify the point. Here are the exceptions that I got. I did try with jmeter.properties , user.properties  files but nothing was worked. I changed the SSLv3 to SSL as well.

```
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:404)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:935)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:646)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:2155)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:2123)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
```

```
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:935)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:646)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:2155)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:2123)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
```

```
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:404)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:935)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:646)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:2155)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:2123)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone help me with this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stacktraces don't tell the full story, to get more verbose information about the handshake and related problems add the next line to *system.properties* file

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

More information: [Diagnosing TLS, SSL, and HTTPS](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/diagnosing-tls-ssl-and-https)

most probably you're using lower version, less secure protocol and the server requires higher version of the protocol. You can check which protocols are being used using

- [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) tool like `openssl s_client -connect -debug your-host
- or [nmap](https://nmap.org/) tool like `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 your-host`

once you figure out which protocol is being used you can enable it via `https.protocols` system property like:

```
 https.protocols=TLSv1.3
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by disabling SSL in the jmeter.properties file in the bin folder:

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me, when spinning up master and slave jmeter nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the test with only one thread. If you don't get this error with only one thread, the problem can be about your system under test gets overloaded and cannot properly respond and end the connection.

If this is not the case, make sure that you have enabled TLS 1.2 in your application (JVM argument?)(-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2). You can use openssl to check the connection and see if you are getting a certificate. Then check your keystore and make sure you have the correct certificate. This will help you to get a proper authorization.

Comment: Did with a single thread. Got the same issue but one time. Its because of the single thread I think. This is a PHP project and hosted in a cloud. Using Jmeter on local to test it. Can you explain how to do this configurations on TLSv1.2 please? The domain was added to the Cloud Flare as well. In there, I have selected TLSv1.2 as Minimum TLS Version and enabled the TLS 1.3 as well. Can you give a help on that?

Comment: Pastebin link to the error code: https://pastebin.com/aJqwi3v7